# Finding the maximum and average value of a function

Tags: python

I want to find the maximum value of a defined function, f(x), in the given range [a,z]. a < z.  there will be n+1 samples (n is inputted in the function) that are equal in size. I also want to find the average value of f(x), with the same conditions. How should I go about beginning to solve this?

Comment: according scipy doc, the second parameter of fmin should be a ndarray that contains initial guess.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is it on strike? Have you tried negotiating with its union leader?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
maximum = max(map(lambda x: -f(x), my_list)  //or
maximum = max(x, key=lambda l: -f(l))


average = sum(my_list)/len(my_list)
```